# GLM Vector initialisation

Tags: c++, glm-math

just a quick question regarding GLM.
I am new to C++ and GLM so bear with me.

I do not understand what this line does:

```
glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

What is "vec" ? A method name ? A constructor ? If I refactor it (rename it), it still works.

I know it must be a variable but it looks like a method to me.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it is a variable -- initialized from its 4-parameters constructor.

Comment: This looks like you need to brush up on basic C++ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

glm::vec4 is a vector with 4 components x,y,z and w.

```
glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
```

Creates a variable named vec of type vec4. The contents of the vector are initialised with

```
x = 1.0f,
y = 0,
z = 0,
w = 1.0f
```

Comment: I have never seen a variable name before, followed by parentheses. How does the parser knows its a variable or a method?

Comment: You might want to mention that this is a stack variable, not something allocated with `new`

Comment: @Trt. You really need to read a C++ tutorial

Comment: The parser knows, that it is a constructor by trying to match the call with all implemented constructors. Please check out a c++ tutorial. It will become clear to you.

Comment: @ OutOfBound Ok when I do this: vecBLAHBLAH(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); it still works. Is there an implementation of a constructor named  vecBLAHBLAH ? I come from a java background, so I am assuming it is using the parameters as a way to identify the constructor ? ?

Comment: If you  compile a line like `type identifier(params...)`, the compiler will look for a member function in type with name type and a matching parameter list. So it will call `type::type(params...)`.